# template class specialization enable_if and default values

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following

```
template <typename T, typename Enable=void>
struct test{};

template <typename T,
    typename std::enable_if< some_trait<T>::value >::type >
struct test{};
```

assuming `some_trait<T>::value` is `true`,  `enable_if<T>::type` is `void`, and the specialization is selected.
However, my query is related to the selection when the follow is the case.

```
template <typename T,
    typename std::enable_if_t< some_trait<T>::value,T>::type >
struct test{};
```

When a second non void template parameter for `enable_if` is provided for `::type`, the unspecialized template 
is selected, even when `some_trait<T>::value` is `true`, as `::type` is `T` instead of `void`, and so doesn't
match the default value in the primary template.

My question is where in the standard is the ordering described for which template is chosen, and why is
the instanciation `test<T,void>` considered as a better match then `test<T,T>`.

https://ideone.com/7v4TTS

full sample :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T,typename Enable=void>
struct test
{
    const char* value = "Primary";
};

#if 1// toggle this

template <typename T>
struct test<T,typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<T,T>::value >::type > 
{
    const char* value = "Specialization";
};

#else

template <typename T>                                    
struct test<T,typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<T,T>::value,T >::type> 
{                                                          ///  ^    
    const char* value = "Specialization";
};

#endif

int main() {
    test<int> v;
    std::cout << v.value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, this is why [`std::void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) was added in C++17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is where in the standard is the ordering described for which template is chosen, and why is the instanciation `test<T,void>` considered as a better match then `test<T,T>`.

[[temp.class.spec.match]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.spec.match).

You wrote `test<int>`, which means that you didn't provide any template argument for the second parameter. Because it has a default parameter, it is chosen, so you actually have `test<int, void>`.

Now, according to the text linked above, the template parameters are matched to a specialization.

In the first case, the specialization is `test<int, void>` after evaluation, and so it is an exact match and chosen.

In the second case, the specialization is `test<int, int>` after evaluation, which is not an exact match and so the primary template is chosen instead of that specialization.

Answer (score 5):

In the first case you have the type

```
std::enable_if< true, void >
```

In the second case you have the type

```
std::enable_if< true, int >
```

`std::enable_if< true, int >::type` is `int`. It doesnt qualify a as type for `typename Enable`, which was requested to be `void`

Comment: @rmawatson `test<int>` is, by the definition of your template, the same as `test<int, void>`. Your `#if 0` case introduces a specialisation for `test<T, T>`, which would be matches by `test<int, int>`, but not by `test<int, void>`.

Comment: @Angew ahh, of course - this is the answer I was looking for -thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`test<int> v;` is `test<int, void> v;` (thanks to default type).

`test<int, int> v;` would select your last specialization.